# 'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command when executed in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, ant

Im developing a program where a batch file will execute Selenium TestNG in ant when run. That batch file works well if i open it by double clicking (which means there is nothing wrong in ANT). But when i try to open this file using java code with the following code it opens in cmd and gives the error below the code. Even though it works with double click i have to make it work with Java code. So this question is different from questions asked before. SO please dnt tell that the question exists. Thanks in advance

```
Runtime.getRuntime()
                        .exec("cmd /c start C:" + File.separator
                                + "Users"
                                + File.separator
                                + "nvithushan" 
                                + File.separator
                                + "Desktop"
                                + File.separator
                                + "HSBC"
                                + File.separator
                                + "gen"
                                + File.separator
                                + "seleniumwebdriver"
                                + File.separator
                                + "HSBC_Demo"
                                + File.separator
                                + "run.bat");
```

running...
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: is ant in your `%PATH%` ?

Comment: yeah... It works with double click

Comment: not what meant. Type `echo %path%` in command prompt and check if `ant\bin` directory is there.

Comment: yeah it is there. And i found the answer for this question.  but thanks alot for stopping by. Ill post the ans below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set ANT in build path of eclipse and added this code. It worked for me.

```
Runtime.getRuntime()
                        .exec("cmd /c start run.bat", null, new File("C:\\Users\\nvithushan\\Desktop\\HSBC\\gen\\seleniumwebdriver\\HSBC_Demo"));
```